# Error writing lock file on Bash/nano using Python on Windows 10

Tags: bash, python, nano, git-bash

I use

```
$ sudo nano first.py
```

or

```
$ nano first.py
```

to start a new nano file (in Python), while using Bash on Windows 10, but the file won't save.

The error I get when I try to save the file is:

> [ Error while writing first.py: Access denied ]

Any ideas? I cannot find answers anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: (1) As a matter of nomenclature, you’re not starting a new nano file in Python, you’re creating a new Python file in nano.  (2) More importantly, what directory are you in when you do this?  Does a ``first.py`` file already exist?  What happens if you type ``> first.py``? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the Ubuntu installation in Windows. I had similar issues and a reinstall helped. Try reinstalling Ubuntu on Windows

To reinstall:

Run PowerShell as Administrator and then

```
lxrun /uninstall
```

Press "y". And then reinstall with

```
lxrun /install
```

Press "y". It takes about 10 min to reinstall. Hope that helps.